# How to monitor downtime of a remote third party MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql, monitoring, prometheus

I have a server application on my own server that depends on remote MySQL db running on another server maintained by a third party. How do I monitor when their bd works and when not? I would like my already deployed Prometheus to scrape it but I can't install exporter on their machine. Is there some kind of mysql pinger for Prometheus or something? If not maybe there is another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple script to bind to the database works for me when I need to monitor remote MySQL instances. I prefer Python because it integrates well with my monitoring system, but any script that binds to the database and executes a simple query will do. I like to use `SELECT NOW()`, but it might be helpful to actually run a query against your data set.

Here's a rough example of a script I'd use to make sure that a remote server is up:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys

try:
    con = mdb.connect('Your Remote Host', 'DB User', 'DB Password', 'DB Name');
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT NOW()")
    ts= cur.fetchone()
    ## Query was successful
    print "Today's date : %s " % ts

except mdb.Error, e:
    ## Something failed, add logic to catch errors here
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

finally:    
    if con:    
        con.close()
```